# Angular call custom function in HttpClient Error Handler

Tags: angular, typescript, error-handling

I am trying to call a custom function in my error handling function but it won't work

my initial function looks like this:

```
register(model: LoginDto) {
  return this.http.post(this.baseURL + 'register', model).pipe(
    catchError(this.handleError)
  );
}
```

and my Error Handling function like this:

```
private handleError(error: any) {
console.log(error);
if (error != null && error instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
  if (error.error != null) {
    const x = Object.keys(error.error).map(key => error.error[key]);
    const y = this.handleHttpError(x);
  }
}
return throwError(error);
}
```

in the Function handleHttpError i would check the error message but when i call it i get the error message *TypeError: this.handleHttpError is not a function*

what am i doing wrong ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to pass the error,

```
 return this.http.post(this.baseURL + 'register', model).pipe((catchError(err => this.handleError(err)));
```